# How can I JSON serialize a Python generic class?

Tags: python, json, generics, serialization

I want to serialize a generic Python class:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
import json

T = TypeVar('T')

class MyGenericClass(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, param: T) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.param = param
    pass

r = MyGenericClass[str]('test')
print(json.dumps(r, default= lambda o: o.__dict__))
```

But I receive the following exception:

> AttributeError: 'mappingproxy' object has no attribute '**dict**'. Did you mean: '**dir**'?

I searched a lot on why I receive such error, but I didn't find any relevant result.

How can I resolve the issue?